# How to get facebook page posts on website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Hi I have a facebook page (not an app), and I want to get the recent post on my website using PHP.

I don't know where to begin. I used google to look this up but all I could find was how to get post from an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very broad question. Anyways, just follow these steps-

1. If you are not registered as a facebook developers, register here: https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Then, create an app from here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps
3. Copy the **app access token** (`app-id|app-secret`) to your php script- this is required, since to fetch the posts (public) from a page, you need a valid access token.
4. Get the contents using `curl` or `file_get_contents` of the url:

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id/page-username}/posts?access_token={app-access-token}
   ```

(You can see the result by browsing above url in a browser) Just parse the JSON and get the posts as required. You'll not get all the posts in one go, but in the result you'll have the url to the next page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try that. So the app doesn't need be connected to my page?

Comment: Nope. You can do the same to fetch the public posts of any page on facebook.

Comment: Okey Thanks! I will try that:) of course I'm gonna vote, just need to try it:)

Comment: I get an error:

'Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"|\".\" at character 15: 000000000000000|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

How do I solve that?

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem, it should be access_token= instead of fields=. 

But thanks a lot for all the help :)

Comment: With the latest API this solution doesn't work. You won't have permission to do so.